# PDFTron: PTFileAttachment with custom image is not showing

Tags: ios, swift, pdftron

I am in the phase of finalizing the PDFTron and I am trying some important features. There is a necessity of showing an image on the PDF and to react on user interaction. Through the given example I found that I have to use `PTFileAttachment`as follows:

```
let file_attach = PTFileAttachment.createFileAttch(withPath: doc.getSDFDoc(), pos: PTPDFRect(x1: 80, y1: 280, x2: 200, y2: 320), path: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "peppers", ofType: "jpg"), icon_name: e_ptPushPin)
first_page.annotPushBack(file_attach)
```

It seems that even in the given example it is not working. The `PTFileAttachment` is showing a push pin rather than showing an image. Therefore my questions are:

1. Is the above mentioned approach is correct to present an image on the PDF with user interaction? else what is the right approach?
2. Why it is not woking? what I have to do more?
3. How to set then image's aspect ratio like widescreen, letterbox or pan and scan.

Thanks!

**Question to you Ryan**

Let's say there is a floor plan (pdf) and I have to position and display all the windows there with the exact picture (graphical representation of the particular window). In other words just to position a image on a pdf simply. PDF can be 600 units x 600 units in scale and image can be 40 units x 40 units at x: 200 and y:300 position. There can be many windows.

According to PDFTron's documentation `PTFileAttachment` is the right tool fulfill the requirement but how to use that is the question. From your own samples there is a sample knows `Miscellaneous Swift Samples` for `Annotations` but it seems not working too. I tried your code which you gave as an answer with many corrections and still it shows the `push pin` rather than showing the image.

**Reproduction steps**

1. Copy and past your own code
2. Copy the image `peppers.jpg`
3. Run and you will see only the push pin rather than the `peppers.jpg`

Comment: There are a few options to add an image to a PDF, so knowing more about your requirements would help. What exactly do you mean by "and to react on user interaction"?

Comment: User interaction is simply a touch. Using the delegate I can open a popup.

Comment: So no move/resize? What does the popup do/display?

Comment: Move and resize is also one of the requirements, but with this question I would like to display a picture of a window (a real window) and user can select a status of that window. Finally the selection will be pushed back to the server.

Comment: If my answer below does not answer your question, please update your question with more details about what you want to accomplish, since it is still unclear to me what you are trying to do. Then I can provide a better answer.

Comment: The documentation says `A RubberStamp annotation displays text or graphics intended to look as if they were stamped on the page with a rubber stamp.` Therefore it is not going to be my option. If you could simply tell `How to use PTFileAttachment` would be helpful.

Comment: I updated my answer, to show how to change the appearance of a FileAttachment annotation (it is the same as changing the appearance of any annotation).

Comment: I modified our AnnotationTest.swift sample file from the MiscellaneousSwiftSamples project that comes with our SDK. I updated my answer below with the code that I used. I ran on simulator and got a PDF with a FileAttachment annotation with the custom image. Other than some syntax issues, my original code worked.

Comment: Can you please post a screen shot of what you see (where you see the push pin and not the custom image appearance), and Clearly show in the screen shot what Application you are using for viewing the PDF.

Comment: Yes your earlier code worked too. I am really sorry because I didn't call pdfView.setDoc(pdfDocument)`.

Comment: Will you please answer my 3rd question. The presented image lost it's aspect ratio    and rendered it self inside the given rectangle. I really want to keep image's aspect ration regardless of the annotation's rectangle.

Comment: Normally the annotation would be created with same aspect ratio, if not the size of the image itself (taking into account image DPI), so this is not normally an issue. What determines the size of the annotation then, if not the image? Regardless, probably best to ask the 3rd question as an entirely new SO posting, since the answer is almost as long my answer below.

Comment: OK, thanks for your support.

Comment: Regarding your third question, did my previous comment help? If you would like assistance with the aspect ratio, please do not hesitate to ask a new SO question. Just add the pdftron tag and we will be sure to see it.

Comment: @Ryan Yes in a way I got an answer but if I really need a help I will.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to change the appearance of a file attachment annotation:

```
func createImageAppearance(doc: PTPDFDoc, img: PTImage) -> PTObj {
    let builder: PTElementBuilder = PTElementBuilder()
    let writer: PTElementWriter = PTElementWriter()
    writer.writerBegin(with: doc.getSDFDoc(), compress: true)
    let w: Int32 = img.getWidth()
    let h: Int32 = img.getHeight()
    let element = builder.createImage(withCornerAndScale: img, x: 0, y: 0, hscale: Double(w), vscale: Double(h))
    writer.writePlacedElement(element)
    let appearance_stream: PTObj = writer.end()
    appearance_stream.putRect("BBox", x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: Double(w), y2: Double(h))
    return appearance_stream
}

let image: PTImage = PTImage.create(doc.getSDFDoc(), filename: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "peppers", ofType: "jpg"))
let file_attach: PTFileAttachment = PTFileAttachment.createFileAttch(withPath: doc.getSDFDoc(), pos: PTPDFRect(x1: 80, y1: 280, x2: 200, y2: 320), path: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "peppers", ofType: "jpg"), icon_name: e_ptPushPin)
first_page.annotPushBack(file_attach)
let app_stm: PTObj = createImageAppearance(doc: doc, img: image)
file_attach.setAppearance(app_stm, annot_state: e_ptnormal, app_state: "")
```

Comment: Thanks and I really appreciate your effort. But the solution is simply not working.

Comment: What exactly did not work? Can you provide screenshot(s), and steps? I want to assist you, but I am still unclear on what you want to do, and what is not working exactly.

Comment: @Goppinath is this still an issue for you? If so, please provide details so I can assist further.

Comment: Question has been updated. Please try your own code in Xcode then you can easily reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Goppinath were you able to solve the problem with pftTron? when uploading an image it shows a pin, even in the demo when you try to upload an image what it shows is a pin, I don't understand what happens, could you solve it?

Comment: @JulianProg I believe this particular question was solved. What is the issue you are running into? Unless your question matches this one exactly, I would suggest making a new SO question entirely.

Comment: @Ryan Sorry to ask directly here. If the pdf has some frames to be filled by photos, for example, the frames have a size of 200px x 200px, do you think it is possible that when uploading an image with the 'stamp' function, the image will automatically adapt to the selected frame of the pdf? I am starting to use that SDK and I am not very familiar, although I read the docs...

Comment: PDFTron offers different SDKs. This SO question was for iOS SDK. Is that the platform you are asking about? Either way, please create a new SO question so I can best assist.

Comment: @Ryan I am implementing the sdk for angular. If I ask the question, could you help me anyway?

Comment: @Ryan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64543845/it-would-be-possible-to-upload-an-image-and-it-automatically-adapts-to-the-size