# It would be possible to upload an image and it automatically adapts to the size of a specific box in the pdf?

Tags: angular, image, sdk, pdftron

I started to work on a code that was already made and they used the pdfTron sdk to edit a pdf, what they want to achieve is that when uploading an image, it adjusts to the automatic size that each box has for images. Let me explain: in the image that I show there are several frames intended for the user to insert their image there, if the user selects to upload their image to box # 1 then the image would have to adapt to the size of box # 1, I am starting a job , I still don't have much experience, I don't know if it's because I don't have a lot of experience that I can't find how to do it or is that way not very feasible? I would like to read the opinion of someone with experience, I am reading the pdfTron documentation but I cannot find something to help me, that is, there should be a way to detect the size of each box intended for the photos and make the image adapt at that size, but how could it?

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8AzQ.jpg)

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a sample PDF with these "rectangles"?

Comment: Hi Ryan. The pdf is the same as the image I show, only that some sheets may have 3 frames (for 3 photos) and other sheets may have more frames, it is the same as the photo. do you think that is possible with the pdfTron? or do you think it would be better to implement another form with pure code? what I want is for the print or image to fit 100% of the size of the boxes without the user having to be moving the image and resizing its size until it fits into the box.

Comment: @Ryan I just uploaded a complete image, where it says "text", the user should be able to write a text that does not leave that available space inside the black box, and in the boxes for the images, the user should be able to upload an image for each box that you select and that fits the size of each frame. Is that possible using the pdfTron (Free version)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it should be possible.
However, I would like to know more about the requirements.
Would it be possible to share the code you have so far?

Are you trying to add an image to a page of particular PDF?
Or you are trying to add a viewer into an HTML page?

Edit: Please see comment

Comment: what it tries to do is that each frame of the PDF can be "clickable", that when the user clicks on which frame of the PDF the window opens to allow them to select a photo and upload it to said frame and adapt to it, that is say, that the image is within that box that I clicked. Would it be possible using that PDFTron? because I don't see something that can help me.

Comment: Based on the information you have provided. Please try out the following:
1. Figure out the coordinate system of the "Frame" and convert it to be in Viewer Coordinates ( https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/coordinates?searchTerm=coordinate )

2. create a stamp annotation ( https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/create-annotation-stamp/ )
You may need to convert the image into a base 64 PNG string

When creating the stamp annotation, set the X,Y, width and height to match that of the rectangle from step 1.